# How to conect a (non android) java app to firebase Storage and upload files?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to connect my java aplication to firebase storage but I can´t find a way to do it, I can´t find any jar file o something to get the connection. I really need help doing the connection and uploading files

Answer (score 0):

What you're calling "Firebase Storage" is actually Google Cloud Storage with APIs for mobile and web apps.  If you have a java program that needs to use Cloud Storage, you should use the [Cloud Storage SDK](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) for java.

You might want to read more about the [relationship between Firebase and Google Cloud when dealing with Cloud Storage](https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-storage-a33fad7c2b80).